# Is Gohan stronger than Vegeta in the DBS manga?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

So in the last chapter of the manga,

> Gohan and Kefura knocks each other out. A Kefura which is a fusion combining a legendary super saiyan who was able to overpower Golden Freezer and defeat Aniraza, and a fusion who can turn into super legendary saiyan 2 .

In the other hand, I dont remember seeing much from Vegeta in the manga. Is Gohan stronger than Vegeta in the DBS manga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters have been power scaled pretty differently in the manga and anime. Gohan in the manga is stronger than his anime counterpart. I'm personally finding the recent scaling in the Manga to be pretty absurd. We see **Master Roshi dodge punches from Jiren/ a being stronger than a God of Destruction (Note: Even if you consider Roshi to be a better martial artist, someone who wasn't even phased by the Timeskip, who is on guard all the time and dodges attacks from UI Omen Goku, is just absur.d).**

Nevertheless, to answer your question, **Gohan from the manga, is definitely not stronger than Vegeta from the manga**. Vegeta in the manga scales up to Mastered Super Saiyan Blue Goku. Toppo stated during his fight with Vegeta in *Manga Chapter 36*, that Vegeta was relative to Goku in terms of sheer power. Hence, Gohan being stronger than Goku would technically make no sense and since Vegeta is as strong as Goku, I think it is still fair to assume the two of them are on the same level.

Comment: But Toppo was wrong, because Goku has Ultra Instinct in the manga and Vegeta doesnt. He might be as strong as Goku without using UI, I suppose. But that's a good point. I forgot Vegeta has mastered super saiyan blue who made Goku able to fight fused Zamasu. Anyway, Kefura has to be stronger than fused Zamasu, since she is the fusion of Kale who is shown to be stronger than Goku Black

Comment: @Pablo Toppo wasn't wrong as he mentioned the same before Goku attained UI. Kefla is definitely weaker than the Light of Divine justice Corrupted Zamasu(Fought evenly with Vegito Blue in the manga) and also weaker than Fused Zamasu from the manga as SSJB mastered Goku fights evenly with Fused Zamasu and Gohan definitely is not > Mastered SSJB Goku.

Comment: @Pablo Also, the potara fusion seemed to be different in the manga as Vados remarked Kefla was as strong as Kale with Caulifla's fighting skills. This is obviously not the general product of potara fusion as in the case of Vegito, in the Buu saga, was obviously substantially stronger than SSJ3 Goku(Who was substantially stronger than SSJ2 Vegeta) and also, they both possess equal fighting skills with Goku probably having the edge.